# Image.network(snapshot[index].data["image"] no longer works?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm following a class and he uses `Image.network(snapshot[index].data["image"],` `["image"]` is where I get the error. I tried using `.get("image")` from another question but no luck.

I have this:

```
  late StreamSubscription<QuerySnapshot>subscription;
  late List<DocumentSnapshot>snapshot;
  CollectionReference collectionReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Latest Post");

  @override
  void initState() {
    subscription = collectionReference.snapshots().listen((datasnap) {
      setState(() {
        snapshot = datasnap.docs;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

```
child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index){
                return Container(
                  width: 350.0,
                  child: Row(children: [
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: Image.network(snapshot[index].data["image"],
```

But am getting `The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object? Function()'. Try defining the operator '[]'.` as the error message.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.get` to get image filed

```dart
Image.network(snapshot[index].get(["image"]),
```

Or this, but it will throw error when data is null.

```dart
Image.network((snapshot[index].data()! as Map)["image"]),
```

Use `errorBuilder` to

```dart
ListView.builder(
    itemCount: snapshot.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      final data = snapshot[index].data() as Map?;
      if (data == null) return Text("got null");
      return Container(
          width: 350.0,
          child: Row(children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Image.network(
                data["image"] ?? "",
                errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) =>
                    Text("got error on image loading"),
              ),
            )
          ]));
    })
```

Comment: Thank you for verifying that works! Went back and realized I had the wrong collection name in my firebase console...